# In Mac OS, Pycharm cannot find python 2.7.14

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pycharm

The pycharm cannot find python 2.7.14

I have just update the version of python from 2.7.10 to 2.7.14. When I check the version in terminal by `python --version` or `python2 --version`, the version is 2.7.14.

However, when I am using pycharm, it still use the 2.7.10 and I cannot find python 2.7.14.

I have try `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python --version`, and the version is 2.7.14. When I try `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 --version` the version is 2.7.10.

so how can I delete the version of 2.7.10 and set pycharm as 2.7.14?

Comment: Instead of mucking with (and potentially breaking) the system, look here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a necessary library for the mac os system, so DO NOT DELETE IT at all costs, you'll break your OS. You need to tell PyCharm to use another Python version, which can be found under settings (Python Interpreter), where you'll be able to find your new version.

Comment: thanks, I add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` as a new interpreter and it works. However, I am a little confused, does that mean `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7` is for system setting and `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7` is for users' setting? When I change the 2.7.14, the package I have installed has gone, dose that mean I should install packages in a user path?

Comment: OSX uses Python as a component, but the user can also use this Python lib and install packages. However, when you installed 2.7.14, you set up a new Python environnment. And packages are not shared between envs, so you need to install packages for your new env, by using `pip` inside your Pycharm terminal or in regular terminal but using your env pip